# Convert Sheet to PDF missing images

Tags: excel, vba, image, pdf

I am using this code to convert sheet to pdf file.I must mention that my Excel Sheet also contains images in each cells on a Column.

```
Sub SheetToPDF()

    Dim wsA As Worksheet
    Dim wbA As Workbook
    Dim strName As String
    Dim strPath As String
    Dim strFile As String
    Dim strPathFile As String
    Dim myFile As Variant
    Dim lOver As Long
    On Error GoTo errHandler

    Set wbA = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wsA = ActiveSheet

    'get active workbook folder, if saved
    strPath = wbA.Path
    If strPath = "" Then
      strPath = Application.DefaultFilePath
    End If
    strPath = strPath & "\"

    strName = "test"


    'create default name for savng file
    strFile = strName & ".pdf"
    strPathFile = strPath & strFile

    If bFileExists(strPathFile) Then
      lOver = MsgBox("Overwrite existing file?", _
        vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "File Exists")
      If lOver <> vbYes Then
        'user can enter name and
        ' select folder for file
        myFile = Application.GetSaveAsFilename _
          (InitialFileName:=strPathFile, _
              FileFilter:="PDF Files (*.pdf), *.pdf", _
              Title:="Select Folder and FileName to save")
        If myFile <> "False" Then
          strPathFile = myFile
        Else
          GoTo exitHandler
        End If
      End If
    End If

    'export to PDF in current folder
    wsA.ExportAsFixedFormat _
        Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        Filename:=strPathFile, _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=False

    'confirmation message with file info
    MsgBox "Successfully created PDF file: " _
      & vbCrLf _
      & strPathFile

    exitHandler:
        Exit Sub
    errHandler:
        MsgBox "Could not create PDF file :("
        Resume exitHandler
    End Sub
    '=============================
    Function bFileExists(rsFullPath As String) As Boolean
      bFileExists = CBool(Len(Dir$(rsFullPath)) > 0)
    End Function
```

The problem is that the PDF file is missing images (only last 2 pages copied the images successfully)
Is there any code to help me copy all images from the excel sheet to PDF file?

Thank you very much!

Comment: If you export the sheet to PDF manually, does it have the images or is it missing them?

Comment: @BigBen Yes,I tried to export it manually but I get the same result

Comment: Doesn't seem like a code issue then. I would try searching along [these lines](https://www.google.com/search?q=excel+export+to+pdf+images+missing).

Comment: @BigBen I also tried **right-click on images -> Size and Properties ->Properties** and it seems that **Print Object checkbox** is checked but still no luck